# PowerBI repeat rows from table A for each date in table B

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables one contains User data and other is my dates table.
Is it possible to copy each row from users table for each date from dates table like below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using transformations:

[image]

Add custom column(column formula is second table name):

[image]

Expand column:

[image]

[image]